# How to read a string from input in Pascal and operate on it?

Tags: string, pascal

I have an unknown number of strings ranging from 50-10^9. I need to read them string by string and do with them something. But I can't figure out how can I read them one by one. Any ideas ?

Comment: Reading them from a file or from input?

Comment: I am reading them from an input

Comment: You may opt to **show** a bit more of that <_something_> as it defines what input-handling strategy is feasible and what is not ( memory-wise, process-wise, concurrency-wise, real-time-performance-wise, to name just a few aspects thereof ).

Comment: That's what I need to figure out. I don't know how much strings I will get and all I need to do with them is to get their length and then write them on the screen

Comment: In that case the **10^9** has no impact on the subject -- read inputString, get len( inputString ), print both, go for next loop. Where is the problem then?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to make it jump on the next string. :D

Comment: Would you kindly post your code-snippet, what you have tested on your own so far?

Comment: I have nothing by now. I am just thinking now how to do that "jumping"

Answer (score -1):

Where you getting your data?

Is it in an array? foreach?
A for in loop has the following syntax:

```
Array loop
procedure ArrayLoop(A: Array of Byte);
var
  B: Byte;
begin
  for B in A do
    DoSomething(B);
end;
```

Comment: No, as I said. I will get an random text from Lorem Ipsum. And i need to know how to jump from string to string

Comment: @Traabefi A string is a list of characters. You mixed it up and mean word, right?

Comment: Yeah. I thought it's the same thing